# In Perforce, recursively list all child streams given a parent stream

Tags: perforce

Given a parent stream, I can find its direct child streams with the below command:

```
p4 streams -F "Parent=<parent_stream_path>"
```

However, is there a way to recursively list all its offspring streams of the given parent stream?

Answer (score 0):

Why not write a script in the preferred language to do this?

Start with the parent. Initialise a queue with the parent as the only element. Get the list of child streams using `p4 streams`. Store them in the queue and append the first node(parent) to a different list. Repeat this procedure with each child as a parent node. Basically, a [Breadth First Search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) with the parent as the root node.

Answer (score 0):

I've written a small perl function to get the children list. 
Something like this one:

```
sub getChildrenList {
  my $child = shift;
  $child =~ s/^\s+|\s+$//g;
  my $get_children_cmd="p4 streams -F \"Parent=<parent_stream_path>\"";
  my @children= `$get_children_cmd`;
  if (@children != 0){
  foreach my $child_name (@children){
    getChildrenList($child_name);
    }
  }
  push(@children_list,$child);
}
```